# Appending to HttpParams adds to map property in one method, but not the other

Tags: angular, typescript, http, parameters

I'm making a request with some optional HttpParams by appending them. In one method inside of my service, this adds the params to the `map` property. In the neighboring method within the same service, after appending `map` is still null.

I create the HttpParams, then append what I need.

The entire working method looks like this.

```
    const user = this.sessionHelperService.checkUser();
    const headers = this.sessionHelperService.getAuthHeader();
    const apiUrl = `${this.LAB_URL_CHUNK}/${user.lab}/${this.LOG_BOOK_INSTRUMENTS_URL_CHUNK}/`;
    let params = new HttpParams();
    pageIndex++;
    params = params.append('page', pageIndex.toString());
    params = params.append('page_size', pageSize.toString());
    params = params.append('paginate', 'true');
    if (locationId) {
      params = params.append('location_id', locationId.toString());
    }

    return this.http.get<LogBookInstruments[]>(apiUrl, { headers, params })
      .pipe(
        catchError((res: HttpResponse<any>) => observableThrowError(res.status)));
```

The method that isn't forming params correctly looks like this. They're extremely similar, so I don't know why the params are being formed differently.

```
    const user = this.sessionHelperService.checkUser();
    const headers = this.sessionHelperService.getAuthHeader();

    sortColumn = sortDirection === '' ? '' : sortDirection === 'asc' ? sortColumn : '-' + sortColumn;
    const apiUrl = `${this.LAB_URL_CHUNK}/${user.lab}/${this.LOG_BOOK_ENTRIES_URL_CHUNK}/?sort=${sortColumn}`;
    let params = new HttpParams();
    pageIndex++;
    params = params.append('page', pageIndex.toString());
    params = params.append('page_size', pageSize.toString());
    params = params.append('paginate', 'true');

    return this.http.get<LogEntry[]>(apiUrl, { headers })
      .pipe(
        catchError((res: HttpResponse<any>) => observableThrowError(res.status)));
```

When I log the params inside the working method, it shows the appended params inside of a `map` array, and the `cloneFrom` property is different.

```
cloneFrom: null
encoder: HttpUrlEncodingCodec {}
map: Map(3)
size: (...)
__proto__: Map
[[Entries]]: Array(3)
0: {"page" => Array(1)}
1: {"page_size" => Array(1)}
2: {"paginate" => Array(1)}
length: 3
updates: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object
```

When I log the params inside the new, not working method, the `map` array is null.

```
cloneFrom: HttpParams {updates: null, cloneFrom: null, encoder: HttpUrlEncodingCodec, map: null}
encoder: HttpUrlEncodingCodec {}
map: null
updates: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object
```

Why should such similar methods create params differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using params in get call that's why:

It's

```
return this.http.get<LogEntry[]>(apiUrl, { headers })
```

Instead of :

```
return this.http.get<LogEntry[]>(apiUrl, { headers, params })
```